# Segmentation fault (core dump) but don't know how to fix it

Tags: c, struct, scanf

When trying to input a string of chars, i get a warning

```
warning: 'doc' may be uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitualized]
```

When i run the code, it only allows me to enter the string itself and then it stops.

I tried compiling the code using an online compiler and it returned `segmentation fault (core dumped). I know something is wrong but i don't know how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Pacient{
    char ime_prezime[100];
    int osiguruvanje;
    int broj_pregledi;
}Pacient;

typedef struct MaticenDoktor{
    char ime_prezime[100];
    int broj_pacienti;
    Pacient pacient[200];
    float cena;
}MaticenDoktor;

void najuspesen_doktor(MaticenDoktor *doc, int n){
    int i, j, najgolema_zarabotka=0, najmnogu_pregledi=0, zarabotka, pregledi;
    char najuspesen[100];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        zarabotka=0;
        pregledi=0;
        for(j=0; j<doc[i].broj_pacienti; j++){
            if(doc[i].pacient[j].osiguruvanje==0){
                zarabotka+=doc[i].cena;
                pregledi++;
            }
        }
        if(zarabotka>najgolema_zarabotka){
            najgolema_zarabotka=zarabotka;
            strcpy(najuspesen, doc[i].ime_prezime);
            najmnogu_pregledi=pregledi;
        }
        else if(zarabotka==najgolema_zarabotka){
            if(pregledi>najmnogu_pregledi){
                najgolema_zarabotka=zarabotka;
                strcpy(najuspesen, doc[i].ime_prezime);
                najmnogu_pregledi=pregledi;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s %d %d", najuspesen, najgolema_zarabotka, najmnogu_pregledi);
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, n;
    printf("Vnesi broj na doktori\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    MaticenDoktor *doc;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%s", doc[i].ime_prezime);   //  <---- warning here
        scanf("%d", &doc[i].broj_pacienti);
        scanf("%f", &doc[i].cena);
        for(j=0; j<doc[i].broj_pacienti; j++){
            scanf("%s", doc[i].pacient[j].ime_prezime);
            scanf("%d", &doc[i].pacient[j].osiguruvanje);
            scanf("%d", &doc[i].pacient[j].broj_pregledi);
        }
    }
    najuspesen_doktor(doc, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `MaticenDoktor *doc;` is uninitialized - where do you think your `scanf` call is going to write to?

Comment: well I don't know any better so if I would have to guess, `char ime_prezime[100]` here?

Comment: You never allocated any space for any `MaticenDoktor`, so there also isn't any space allocated for `ime_prezime` (or any other variable you are trying to write to) - what resource are you using to learn C that hasn't covered this yet?

Comment: Assuming the compiler in use supported VLAs then replace `MaticenDoktor *doc` by `MaticenDoktor doc[n]`.

Comment: @UnholySheep from uni presentation but they're not very detailed. They have some examples, but not good explanations. You have to teach the course yourself while paying them to do it.

Comment: @alk the `MaticenDoktor doc[n]` fixed the warning but it still doesn't let me enter the following inputs.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)  3) insert a reasonable space inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators 4) for flexibility, separate a 'struct' definition from a 'typedef' for that struct

Comment: OT: regarding: `zarabotka+=doc[i].cena;`  This is performing an implicit conversion between a `float` and a `int`.  In general, such implicit conversions should be avoided.  Or, at least include a 'cast' so the compiler knows that you know (and accept) the risk in an implicit conversion

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d", &n);` (and similar statements)  Always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  Similar to: `if( scanf("%d", &n) != 1) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed\n" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are from the header file: `stdlib.h`

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", doc[i].ime_prezime);`  When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, when using the input format specifier: `%s` and/or `%[...]`  always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids overflowing the input buffer and the resulting Undefined Behavior  Similar to: `if( scanf("%5s", doc[i].ime_prezime) != 1) {handle error}`

Comment: regarding: `MaticenDoktor *doc;`  All this does is place a uninitialized pointer on the stack.  It does not allocate any memory for that pointer to point to.  So this kind of statement: `scanf("%f", &doc[i].cena);`  is using what ever trash was on the stack at `doc` as a pointer and that could be pointing to anywhere in memory.  Any such access if undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest: `MaticenDoktor doc[ 100 ];`  or `MaticenDoktor *doc = malloc( 100 * sizeof( MaticenDoktor) );  Then `if( !doc ) { perror( "malloc failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MaticenDoktor *doc;` only declares a pointer, and not the full structure (or the array).  You need to initialize it to point to somewhere, where you can warrant there's enough free memory to hold the information.  You can ensure this in several ways:

- You can, instead, hold a complete structure in the function body (`main` in your case, with this similar declaration:

  ```
  MaticenDoktor doc; /* no pointer, but a full structure variable is declared */
  scan("%s", doc.ime_prezime);
  ...
  ```
- You can, declare an array of `MaticenDoktor` structures with the following code:

  ```
  MaticenDoktor doc[100];  /* now doc is an array with space for 100 MaticenDoktors */
  scan("%s", doc[n].ime_prezime); /* n ranges from 0 to 99 max */
  ```
- You can, if you don't know *a priori* how many `MaticenDoktor` you are going to have, and you read it before the loop, with:

  ```
  MaticenDoktor *doc = malloc(n * sizeof *doc); /* you have doc pointing to an array of n MaticenDoktors */
  scan("%s", doc[n].ime_prezime);
  ...
  free(doc); /* after you are completely finished using doc */
  ```
- You can, if you are short of memory, just declare an array of pointers with space for the maximum, and allocate the structures as you need them:

  ```
  MaticenDoktor *doc[1000]; /* space for maximum of 1000 pointers to MaticenDoktor */
  for (i = 0; i < n && i < 1000; i++) {
      doc[i] = malloc(sizeof *doc[i]); /* size of pointed value, not of pointer */
      scanf("%s", doc[i]->ime_prezime);
      ...
  }
  ```

  and later on

  ```
  for (i = 0; i < n && i < 1000; i++) {
       free(doc[i]); /* free space used by doc[i] */
  }
  ```
- ... and many other ways to organize your memory :)

Answer (score 0):

`doc` has not been assigned so points to an unpredictable location. You should either place it on the stack:

assing dynamic memory first.

```
MaticenDoktor *doc;
int len = 10; // all memory that you need.
doc =(MaticenDoktor *)malloc(sizeof(MaticenDoktor)*len);
```

it fix the Warning .

Comment: No need to cast malloc & friends in C nor is it good practise.